# Three monitor setup failes after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04

**EDIT**

No backup, no mercy. I reinstalled the whole system, wiping the installation. No difference. It seems that this problem is either specific to my setup, or related to Ubuntu 20.04.

**ORIGINAL**

After upgrading to 20.04 my three monitor setup broke. I can now only activate the primary display. I am running the nvidia-driver-440 package.

If I set the refresh rate to 144 Hz, the primary displays resolution is doubled to a 3840x1080 pixels. I have to scroll, to reach the left- or rightmost end of my screen. If I set it to 60 Hz, the resolution resets.

Additionally I cannot turn on the other two screens via the ubuntu display settings or nvidia-settings. They are listed as displays and I can active them in the menu, but after applying the configuration it resets to only the primary display. The monitors exit power saving mode once and then resume power saving mode (the power button flashes).
During boot, all screens show the boot screen.

All monitors are plugged into the nvidia card.

Happy with any help.

- partial [nvidia-bug-report.log](https://pastebin.com/XLmmXJt7)
- [Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/ix4L1GQg)

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 144.00   119.98    99.93    84.90  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.93 +  60.00    59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.93 +  60.00    59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 440.64

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```